# Lookup DNS-names outside domain

Tags: networking, dns

how do I configure my DNS server so users can lookup the DNS names outside my domain Linux1.ok?
this should be done recursively.

thanks

Comment: what dns server are you running and how did you configure it?

Comment: How have you set up your network?  We can only make guesses, which could be what you ask for or not.  Usually you have your router/NAT/firewall (Home router) also handling your DNS for your LAN.  And that are usually fixed with DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's sample /etc/dhcpd.conf from `https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server`

```
# Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf
# (add your comments here) 
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.254;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
option domain-name "mydomain.example";

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;
}
```

Notice the line `option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;` You could add there dns servers outside your domain that you want

Comment: @salim:  Don't thank Serg!  ;-) If you like his answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "1" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 1, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... And serg *knows* where the "1" comes from...